# Azure API Management APIs endpoint are not displaying as expected

Tags: xml, url-rewriting, azure-api-management, apim

I created a brand new function app and imported to APIM. I tried below option to align with customer expected APIM endpoint for API. But some are working and others are failed.

I really perplexed a lot to define APIM suffix and Function App route url? what are the best consideration and practices to follow?

Does the `re-writeurl` policy helps in this case?

**Expected Customer APIM endpoint:**

```
https://dev-contoso-apim.azure-api.net/api/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/?serviceId=1&branchId=2&startDate=2024-02-01
```

Function name: `dev-contoso-appointments-func`

APIM Host: `dev-contoso-apim.azure-api.net`

Settings of Appointment APIs collection in APIM.

[image]

The route for function API is defined at server side as shown in below

[image]

**Option 1:** If I change function api route to `Route="availableDates"`at server side and add APIM prefix url as `api/v1.0/appointments` , APIM endpoint is displaying as expected like below and working successfully.

**Question:** I don't want APIM prefix URL to supply as in future if I require V2 version? Can I still add?

**Expected APIM endpoint:**

```
https://dev-contoso-apim.azure-api.net/api/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/?serviceId=1&branchId=2&startDate=2024-02-01
```

**Option 2:** If I retain `Route = "v1.0/appointments/availableDates/"` as it is and set APIM prefix url empty, APIM endpoint is not an expected one but APIM API is successfully working.

**Actual APIM Endpoint:**

```
https://dev-contoso-apim.azure-api.net/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/availableTimes/?serviceId=1&branchId=2&startDate=2024-02-01
```

**Expected APIM endpoint:**

```
https://dev-contoso-apim.azure-api.net/api/v1.0/appointments/api/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/?serviceId=1&branchId=2&startDate=2024-02-01
```

Notice `/api` does not exist in the actual APIM endpoint.

How do I setup my APIM prefix and route in option 2?

[image]

**Option3:** If I retain `Route = "v1.0/appointments/availableDates/"` as it is and set APIM prefix url as `api`, APIM endpoint is an expected one but APIM API is NOT working.

> Error: Resource not found.

How do I setup my APIM prefix and route in option 2?

**Actual APIM Endpoint:**

```
 https://dev-contoso-apim.azure-api.net/api/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/availableTimes/?serviceId=1&branchId=2&startDate=2024-02-01
```

**Expected APIM endpoint:**

```
https://dev-contoso-apim.azure-api.net/api/v1.0/appointments/api/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/?serviceId=1&branchId=2&startDate=2024-02-01
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have set the `route="v1.0/appointments/availableDates/"` in function and imported the function into APIM as shown below-

[image]

[image]

By adding API URL suffix as `api/`, endpoint becomes `https://{apim-name}.azure-api.net/api/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/?serviceId=1&branchId=2&startDate=2024-02-01`. I am able to get the expected output when testing it.

[image]
[image]

Secondly, you can also set the function route to `api/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/` and while importing set APIM suffix to empty.

[Rewrite URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/rewrite-uri-policy#usage-notes) policy can be used to add query string parameters.

[image]

Comment: Begin with first option ```route="v1.0/appointments/availableDates/"``` . Have you tried to import another function app with same APIM suffix```/api```? Are you able to successfully create another API?

Comment: can you also provide me more update on how to use that ```rewrite url``` ?

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS Yes I tried, You can't have two APIs having same suffix. So APIM won't allow to create multiple APIs with same suffix

Comment: Check this MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/rewrite-uri-policy for more info on Rewrite URL policy

Comment: I tried 2nd option setting the function route to ```api/v1.0/appointments/availableDates/``` and while importing set APIM suffix to empty. For now I did not added any query parameters and so never used ```rewrite-url``` policy. I am getting error  ```Resource not Found```

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS Can you please check in the trace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256874/discussion-between-pavankumar-gvvs-and-ikhtesam-afrin).